# Bootstrap / CSS Input Form not centring

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The Bootstrap input form isn't centring even though I have it setup to be.
Here's what it looks like:

Form Not Centering:

[image]

Proper Form

[image]

The red is the problem and the green is what I want. Here is the code.

CSS:

```
.form-control {
  height: 50px;
  width: 330px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

HTML:

```
           <form class="form-inline" role="form">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Enter email address</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email address">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Early Access</button>
                </div>
           </form>
```

All help would be amazing, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jj4B8/2/) fix your problem?

Just added a wrapper around it:

```
#wrapper {
  text-align:center;
}

.form-control {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Well you'll need to post more code. This works for what you posted.

Comment: Your JSFiddle example doesn't work. Check it out, its the same problem I'm having. The form is sticking to the left.

Comment: added `margin: 0 auto` and it seems to be working now, check it again.

Comment: Collapse the result element. It breaks and the form stick to the left

Answer (score 0):

How about something along those lines:

- Wrap your stuff with a `<div class="container">`, centering everything.
- Add an id to that same div and set the width to whatever you want.
- Set the width of your button to 100%.

html:

```
<div class="container" id="myContainer">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Enter email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email address" />
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button id="earlyAccessBtn" type="submit" class="btn">Early Access</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

css:

```
#myContainer {
    width: 350px;
}

#earlyAccessBtn {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/newblt123/hkddL/)