# CSS Bootstrap Centre All Items

Tags: html, css

Im using a modified version of the grayscale bootstrap theme : https://startbootstrap.com/theme/grayscale

I cant seem to get items that are not text to align in the centre. They all end up with loads of strange white space before (see screenshot where i've highlighted to show the whitespace)

How to i create a css style to make sure its always centred?

See the dropdown and img ive added is off to the right and not aligned with the text. Ideally i want it as compact as possible with no whitespace.

```
<!-- Projects-->
        <section class="projects-section bg-light" id="projects">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Featured Project Row-->
                <div class="row align-items-center no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">
                    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-7">
                        <div class="featured-text text-center text-center">
                            <form class="text-white-50 mx-auto mt-2 mb-5" method="POST" action="/result">
                            <h1>Lineup:</h1>
                            <div class="text-pre">
                            <p><h3><b>Team A: {{ scorea }}</b></h3></p>
                            <select id="changeImageA">
                                <option>other</option>
                                <option>blue</option>
                                <option>white</option>
                                <option>black</option>
                                <option>red</option>
                            </select>
                            <img id="imageA" src='/static/other.png' width="50" height="60">
                            <p>{% for player in teama %}{{ player }}<br>{% endfor %}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-pre">
                            <p><h3><b>Team B: {{ scoreb }}</b></h3></p>
                            <select id="changeImageB">
                                <option>other</option>
                                <option>blue</option>
                                <option>white</option>
                                <option>black</option>
                                <option>red</option>
                            </select>
                            <img id="imageB" src='/static/other.png' width="50" height="60">
                            <p>{% for player in teamb %}{{ player }}<br>{% endfor %}</p>
                            </div>
                            <h3><b>Save lineup?</b></h3>
                            <input class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger" type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Store">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger" type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Rerun">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

[image: Example]

Here is my version of the style.css:

https://github.com/bignellrp/footyapp/blob/main/static/styles.css

I tried the following but it made no difference, although im not sure how to auto clear css cache.

CSS

```
.center-item {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.center-text {
text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="center-item"> <select id="changeImageA">
```

URL

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Comment: I'll try a wrapper shortly and see if that helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602021/bootstrap-css-input-form-not-centring

Comment: To clear your browser cache, use the Clear history function. *careful* with clearing history, as your **stored passwords** could be wiped, make sure to have a backup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex display containers to align any types of elements as you wish, here is an example.

```css
div {
display:flex;  /* set the flex display on all div elements */
align-items:center; /* align items to center */
flex-direction:column; /* align in a column instead of a row which is default */
width:80vw;margin-left:10vw;
}

.rect {
background:red;
width:100px;height:25px;
}

button {
align-self:flex-end; /* you can specify a different alignment rule for a given element * /
}
```

```html
<div>
   <button>a button</button>
   <p>Some paragraph text</p>
   <div class="sub-container">
      <span>some other span</span>
      <span class="rect"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this to fix the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/jj4B8/2/

```
#wrapper {
  text-align:center;
}

.form-control {
    margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 330px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```